# What is the difference between a normal user and the root user when connecting via openssl?

Tags: centos, openssl

On a CentOS 6 desktop, when we connect with openssl to a webserver using a NORMAL user:

```
CONNECTED(0000003) SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177
```

It doesn't connect, but if we do it with the root user, it connects.

**Q:** What is the difference when connecting with openssl with different users?

Comment: Different client and / or CA certificates.

Comment: Firewall rules?

Answer (score -1):

There is no tangible difference.

The problem you are having is almost surely related to sshd options. (it could also be some security plugin like Centrify, but that is not likely on a server).

Revise the options in `/etc/sshd/config`, specifically:

```
DenyUsers
DenyGroups
AllowUsers
AllowGroups
```

Comment: it is ssl, not SSH, but thanks!

Comment: SSL is used by many other protocols to secure connections. Said connections (ssh, https, ftp) have configuration options that define how SSL is used. I have assumed that your connection issue is with SSH because you mention connecting with system users. And, well, openssl on its own cannot be used to connect  to anything.

Comment: @Bruno9779, -1 SSH doesn't have anything to do with SSL/TLS. And the [`openssl` command line tool](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities) has a _huge_ bunch of builtin utils, including `s_client` that very much _can_ connect to SSL/TLS speaking servers.